# How Do I Change Icons in the Dock "Plank"?

Tags: icons, customization, settings, dock, plank

I'm wondering how I change icons for specifically the dock "Plank". I've only managed to find a way to change theme, but not icons for the actual applications in the dock.

Is it possible? If so, how do you do it?

The problem is that I want to use Faenza icons for as my usual icons, but another type of icons for my dock.

The current version I'm using is: 0.2.0.796

Answer (score 7):

You should make custom .desktop files with the corresponding icon you wish to appear on your dock, i. e. this is my custom minecraft `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Minecraft
Exec=java -jar /home/myuser/.launchers/Minecraft.jar
Icon=/home/myuser/.launchers/minecraft.png
Type=Application
```

Replacing `Exec` with the program you wish to execute and `Icon` with the full path to your icon, and don't forget giving execution permissions to the file.